# I cant connect gogo shell through terminal in liferay 7.1?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7.1

I cant able to connect gogo shell using following command in linux
**telnet localhost 11311**

face error 
**telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused**

Answer (score 5):

As you have discovered, Gogo Shell is no longer enabled through telnet by default. The [documentation](https://dev.liferay.com/en/develop/reference/-/knowledge_base/7-1/using-the-felix-gogo-shell) says

> Note: You can also interact with Liferay Portal’s module framework via a local telnet session. To do this, you must have [Developer Mode](https://dev.liferay.com/en/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-1/using-developer-mode-with-themes#setting-developer-mode-for-your-server-using-portal-developer-properties) enabled.

And if you look at portal-developer.properties, the key configuration line (that you could just add to your portal-ext.properties file) is

```
module.framework.properties.osgi.console=localhost:11311
```

Or, alternatively, use the Gogo Shell portlet that you can now find in Control Panel - there it's active by default, with no additional configuration option required.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - note that this is what the "Accept" button (a checkmark) is for. ;)